# « Parcours personnel » et « parcours professionnel »

Tags: usage, curriculum-vitae

Quelle est la différence entre parcours personnel et professionnel ?
Dans des CV, j'ai vu les deux tournures utilisées pour parler des formations, diplômes, contrats, affiliations, etc. Peut-on les utiliser de façon interchangeable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Parcours professionnel* est plus restrictif que *Parcours personnel*.

Le premier devrait se limiter à donner des informations sur ce qui à directement trait à sa profession (postes occupés, tâches réalisées, formations reçues après sa formation initiale).

Le deuxième permet d'aborder des sujets sans lien avec sa profession, son pays d'origine, sa famille, ses loisirs, etc.

Lorsqu'il y a une séparation franche entre les études et l'activité professionnelle, la formation et les diplômes (scolaires/universitaires) ne devraient pas être inclus dans le parcours professionnel mais dans un chapitre intitulé *Formation*